# Allow users to register with specific email address domain

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to make a validation on a field, I want to allow users register only with specific domains' emails. For e.g. I want users to register only the emails which are from the company1, company2, company3.
I use this code:

HTML:

```
    <input type="text"/>
    <button>Run</button>
```

Jquery:

```
$('button').on('click', function(){
str = $('input').val();
str = str.split('@').slice(1);

var allowedDomains = ['company1', 'company2', 'company3'];

if ($.inArray(str[0], allowedDomains) !== -1) {
    alert(str + ' is allowed');
}else{
    alert('not allowed');
}
});
```

and it working fine, but the problem i facing that if user enter domain name in uppercase or write first letter in uppercase then lowercase. 
How can i validate to accept both uppercase and lowercase.

Comment: That's not nice to make such checks client-side

Comment: not difficult to convert to lowerCase or search how to do it. Basic research is expected before asking questions and this is really quite trivial

Comment: Nicael is right.. your business rules on the client side gives info and can be curvumvented easily

Answer (score 2):

You can compare the forbidden strings to the *lowercase* version of the user's input email .

```
if ($.inArray(str[0].toLowerCase(), allowedDomains) !== -1) {
```

Also, keep in mind that, if this is an important criteria to you, you should ensure that validations are also done server side, as it easy to bypass the client and send manually forged requests.